# "The located assemblys manifest definition does not match the assembly reference" with nuget packages. Silverlight project

Tags: c#, silverlight, visual-studio-2012, telerik, nuget

So I created a local nuget server to serve our Telerik dlls.
Whenever I use the local dlls on my machine (Without nuget), everything works fine. But when I delete the two references and install them through nuget the build fails with the error:

> Cannot resolve reference assemblies. please check the reference
>   assemblies. Could not load file or assembly 'System.Core,
>   Version=5.0.5.0, Culture=neutral' or one of its dependencies. The
>   located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
>   reference. (Exception from HRESULT:0x80131040)

I have checked that the local telerik DLL is the same version as the one found in the nuget package.

Anyone have a clue?

PS: Silverlight project

Comment: Is it a silverlight project?

Comment: Yes, it is. I will edit the question to specify :)

Comment: Take a look at the raw project file in the ItemGroup where it's including the project references and compare the differences.  Post those results if you need further help.